# PHP: How to pass instance variable to closure?

Tags: php, closures

If you want to use a closure from within a class, how do you pass in an instance variable from that class?

```
class Example {
    private $myVar;
    public function test() {
        $this->myVar = 5;
        $func = function() use ($this->myVar) { echo 'myVar is: ' . $this->myVar; };

        // The next line is for example purposes only if you want to run this code.
        // $func is actually passed as a callback to a library, so I don't have
        // control over the actual call.
        $func();
    }
}
$e = new Example();
$e->test();
```

PHP doesn't like this syntax:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use $this as lexical variable in example.php on line 5
```

If you take off `$this->` then it can't find the variable:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: myVar in example.php on line 5
```

If you use `use (xxx as $blah)` as suggested in some places, it seems invalid syntax whether you have `$this` or not:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ',' or ')' in example.php on line 5
```

Is there a way to do this?  The only way I can get it to work is with a dodgy workaround:

```
$x = $this->myVar;
... function() use ($x) { ...
```

Comment: Your "workaround" at the end is how I would do it.

Comment: Why do you think it's dodgy? As it says, you can't use `$this` as a lexical variable, so you need to use another variable. That's what `$x` is.

Comment: It's dodgy because it adds an extra copy operation.  I have to copy the variable into `$x`, then `$x` gets copied a second time into the closure.  If I could do something like `function () use ($this->myVar as $x)` then it would avoid that extra copy and make the code neater.

Comment: PHP uses lazy copying, it initially just uses references, copying only when one of them is modified.

Comment: FWIW, PHP 5.4 supports `$this` inside closures.

Comment: @FelixKling: Oh you're right: you just use `$this` without a `use` statement at all.  You should post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.4 or later, then you can use `$this` directly inside the closure:

```
$func = function() {
  echo 'myVar is: ' . $this->myVar;
};
```

Comment: It looks like this also includes the parent:: variable in addition to $this, to access the parent class of the object $this (if there is one).

Answer (score 11):

You can use your workaround. You can also be more general:

```
$self = $this;
$func = function() use ($self) {
    echo "myVar = " . $self->myVar;
};
```

Within the closure you can access any public properties or methods using `$self` instead of `$this`.

But it won't work for the original question, because the variable in question is private.

Comment: voodoo417 makes a good point - this will only work with public variables, not private ones.

Comment: Didn't think of that. I've updated my answer to reflect this limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Why not ?:

```
    $func = function($param){ echo 'myVar is: ' . $param; };
    $func($this->myVar);
```

**Update**:

@Bramar right. But, if only $myVar will be `public`, it will work. Closures have no associated scope , so they cannot access private and protected members. In you specific case, you can do:

```
    $this->myVar = 5;   
    $_var = $this->myVar;
    $func = function() use ($_var) { echo 'myVar is: ' . $_var; };
    $func();
```

Comment: Sorry, `$func()` was just for example purposes.  I am really passing this function to a library as a callback, so I have no control over the actual calling of my function.